# Angular convert date before referring to it in routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have the following html in my angular app:

```
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="edate">Expiration Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="expdate" id="edate" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <button type="submit" ui-sref="inventory({ expdate: expdate })" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </div>
```

I would like to convert the `$scope.expdate` variable `$scope.expdate.toUTCString()` before referring it in my `ui-sref`. How do i proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should use the date filter
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

or create your own :

```
app.filter('getUtcDate', [
    function() {
        return function(input) {
            return input.toUTCString();
        };
    }
]);
```

and then you could do :

```
 <button type="submit" ui-sref="inventory({ expdate: expdate|getUtcDate })" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

Edit :
could you simply use :

```
<button type="submit" ui-sref="inventory({ expdate: expdate.toUTCString() })" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

Comment: hi thank you for the answer. I am getting the following error. ...... angular.js:11655 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/syntax?p0=%7C&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=31&p3=%7B%20prod%3A%20prod%2C%20expdate%3A%20expdate%7CgetUtcDate%2C<button type="submit" ui-sref="inventorycreate({ expdate: expdate|getUtcDate })" class="btn btn-primary">%20%7D&p4=%7CgetUtcDate%2C